# Separate Forms into Components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have successfully built a page where it has two forms. I'm having difficulty on how to separate the two forms into separate components. I already added components for each forms. How would I do it the recommend and correct way?

Pls check my stackblitz here [CLICK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-dfy6qp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
this.personalDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ["", Validators.required],
  email: ["", Validators.required],
  phone: ["", Validators.required],
});
this.addressDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
  city: ["", Validators.required],
  address: ["", Validators.required],
  pincode: ["", Validators.required],
});
```

Comment: put input props to recieve the form group inside the components and just use the component selectors inside the app component in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To divide a large .html in two components you can make in three steps

1. Use the same .html that the main.
2. The necesaries variables you use `@Input`, so. e.g. for "personal-info" you need

```
      @Input() personalDetails:FormGroup
      @Input() personal_step = false;
```

3. The functions are eventEmitters, so for personal-info you need

```
    @Output() next:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter<any>()
```

4. Change a bit the .html -really get out the `"*ngIf="step==1"` and
   change the `(click)="next()"` to use the Output

```
    <input (click)="next.emit(null)" .../>
```

5. Some functions are necesary translate to the component
6. You need copy also the .css. I choose put the .css in the styles.css
   (it's common to all the application

I forked your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-myf2q7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpersonal-info%2Fpersonal-info.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you can do something like this:

personal-info.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export interface PersonalInfo {
  name: string
  email: string
  phone: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal-info',
  templateUrl: './personal-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal-info.component.css']
})
export class PersonalInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() personal: PersonalInfo; // <---- input data for your component

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

then in the personal component html:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="personal.name" />
</form>
```

and in your app component, something like:

```html
<personal-info [personal]="currentUser.personalInfo" />
```

Comment: Can you fork my stackblitz?

Comment: In your case, your component input can be the formGroup itself.

Comment: No I'm not gonna do the work for you sorry

Comment: you can try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x8qfze?file=src%2Fapp%2Faddress-form.component.ts @SimonCorcos